# Custom email directive as per Magento 2.4 docs example not working

Tags: magento2.4, email-templates, template-directive

While upgrading our email templates to comply with the security changes introduced in Magento 2.4.3-p2, I'm having trouble creating a custom directive as per the [Magento docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html#create-a-custom-directive).

I tried to use the example from the docs (with modifications to the namespace, of course), but it doesn't seem to work. When I use `{{lifetime_spend}}` inside the email template, that's what I later see in the email, so it doesn't work as expected. I tried this both on Magento v 2.4.3-p2 and also on a clean installation of 2.4.2. Neither is working for me.

Did anyone of you get this example from the Docs working, or successfully implemented your own version?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while trying to follow Magento docs instructions but after some time I was able to get the new email template directive to work.

**What didn't work:** using custom directive name with underscores. While debugging the code I could see the `directiveName` being served in pieces to the `get` function resulting in the exception `vendor/magento/framework/Filter/SimpleDirective/ProcessorPool.php:45`

```
    public function get(string $name): ProcessorInterface
    {
        if (empty($this->processors[$name])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Processor with key "' . $name . '" has not been defined');
        }

        return $this->processors[$name];
    }
```

**What worked:**

- Magento version 2.4.4
- Email templates saved in database which overrides Order Receipt email template
- Used `bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\Filter\SimpleDirective\ProcessorPool"` to verify my custom directive passed into the `processors` array.

```
$bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\Filter\SimpleDirective\ProcessorPool"

DI configuration for the class Magento\Framework\Filter\SimpleDirective\ProcessorPool in the GLOBAL area

Preference: Magento\Framework\Filter\SimpleDirective\ProcessorPool

Constructor Parameters:
+------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name       | Requested Type | Configured Value                                                            |
+------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| processors |                | {                                                                           |
|            |                |     "_vac_": {                                                              |
|            |                |         "mycustomdirective": {                                               |
|            |                |             "_i_": "string Namespace\Module\Model\CustomDirective" |
|            |                |         }                                                                   |
|            |                |     }                                                                       |
|            |                | }                                                                           |
+------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- Make sure the `item name="mycustomdirective"` in (my case global) `di.xml` matched the return string of the `getName()` function class directive which implements `ProcessorInterface`
- Disabled the following caches while developing locally: `config, block_html, full_page`
- Make sure the email template directive usage `{{mycustomdirective}}` (no spaces between curly baces and the directive name) matches the DI and PHP class directive name

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @dchayka, I wish I'd known this earlier. The documentation explicitly gives you an underscore example and so they really need to fix that. This caused me a lot of lost time and I'm most grateful for your response.

I would upvote your response if I had more credit but I'm still < 15.